# Is the number of comparisons a good predictor of the execution time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

For the comparison sorts, is the number of comparisons a good predictor of the execution time? Is a comparison a good choice for analyzing sorting algorithms that use comparisons?

Comment: Yes it is .....

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I respect a person who can so eloquently argue both sides of an issue!  ;-)

Comment: This question it too broad. It really depends on the bunch of factors: Is it in memory or not? Do we copy the objects? Is the copying "heavy" compared to comparison? It's not possible to give a definitive answer without knowing all the details.

Comment: I meant it's opinion based @Codie

Comment: As commented by kraskevich, the number of moves is also a factor as well as cache locality issues for both compares and moves, and as commented by kraskevich, the time it takes to compare versus the time it takes to move. For example, consider sorting an array of pointers to objects, only the pointers are moved, but the objects are compared requiring one deference (of a pointer) for each compare.

Comment: Within limits, yes. That is, you can usually say that Sort A, which requires on the order of `n^2` comparisons, will be slower when sorting a given set of data on a particular machine than Sort B which requires on the order of `n log n` comparisons. That is, if all other things are constant (i.e. cost of comparison, cost of swapping, cost of data access, the data itself, etc.), then you can usually use the number of comparisons to get a rough estimate of execution time.